# How can I add a link within a DropdownItem with reactstrap?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, reactstrap

How can I add a link within a DropdownItem with reactstrap?

I would like to add a link within a dropdown menu, but how can I add it because in the reactstrap documentation I could not find anything related.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Fade, Flip, Rotate, Zoom, Bounce, Stepper } from 'react-reveal';
import Headroom from 'react-headrooms';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

import {Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { ButtonDropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem, NavLink, Link, NavItem } from 'reactstrap';



export default class NavbarBoots extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.toogle = this.toogle.bind(this);
        this.state={dropdownMenu:false}

    }
    toogle() {
        this.setState({dropdownMenu:!this.state.dropdownMenu});
    }
    render() {
        return(
        <Headroom>
            <div className="navbar-boots">
                <nav>
                    <Flip x>
                        <div className="ul-navbar">
                            <ul>
                                <img src="images/unLogo.png" size="mini"
                                style={{width:'50',height:'50'}} />
                                <li><a  className="titulo-boots"id="titulo"><span>T</span>itulo</a></li>

                                <ButtonDropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
                                        <DropdownToggle caret>
                                           Portafolio
                                        </DropdownToggle>
                                        <DropdownMenu className='dropdown-menu'>
                                            <DropdownItem tag={Link} to="/landing" classname='dropdown-item'>ACERCA DE MI</DropdownItem>
                                            <DropdownItem href="#" classname='dropdown-item'><a>PROYECTOS</a></DropdownItem>
                                            <DropdownItem href="http://localhost:3000/vitae" classname='dropdown-item' active>LINKS</DropdownItem>

                                        </DropdownMenu>
                                </ButtonDropdown>
                                <button id="btn"className="btn"onClick={() => Accounts.logout()}>Logout</button>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </Flip>
                </nav>  
            </div>  
        </Headroom>
        ); // return
    };
}
```

it is displayed in this way but I can not add a link

[image]

Answer (score 31):

Incase anyone else is looking for this, here's the proper straightforward solution.

```
<DropdownItem tag={Link} to="/me">text here</DropdownItem>
```

Or if it is meant to be a standard link then,

```
<DropdownItem tag={a} href="/me">text here</DropdownItem>
```

[Source](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/43)

Comment: Alternatively, if you are using a custom component for rendering links, such as https://github.com/TylerBarnes/gatsby-plugin-transition-link or Google Analytics' OutboundLinks, you can use: <Dropdown.Item as={AniLink} /> and <Dropdown.Item as={OutboundLink} /> respectively.

Answer (score 28):

if you use react-bootstrap instead of reactstrap an come across same issue you need to:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Dropdown.Item as={Link} to="/me">text here</Dropdown.Item>
```

Comment: Works Great!  Using <Link> instead of the default, <SafeAnchor>, is really important.  Since my React website uses Gatsby, using <Link> for all internal site links is highly recommended.

Answer (score 5):

```
<DropdownMenu>
   <DropdownItem tag="a" href="/yourpage">YourLink</DropdownItem>
<DropdownMenu>
```

source: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

Answer (score 5):

### 2020 Updated

Looking over these answers suggest `Link` should come from `reactstrap`, yet that doesn't export a `Link` component.

`Link` should come from `react-router-dom`.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  ButtonDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem
} from "reactstrap";

// ...

<ButtonDropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
  <DropdownToggle caret>Actions</DropdownToggle>
  <DropdownMenu>
    <DropdownItem tag={Link} to={`/action`}>Action</DropdownItem>
  </DropdownMenu>
</ButtonDropdown>
```

Comment: To add to this, I used NavLink from react-router-dom as my tag: 
    import { NavLink as RRNavLink } from "react-router-dom";
    <DropdownItem tag={RRNavLink} to={`/action`}>Action</DropdownItem>

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have react-router-bootstrap installed. LinkContainer is the component that will make the link clickable. It must be placed outside of DropdownItem for it to work in Firefox. Also, adding className="collapse" to Collapse component will hide the menu initially in Firefox.

```
npm install react-router-bootstrap --save
```

Pre-requisites:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0
npm install --save reactstrap@next
npm install --save jquery@1.9.1
npm install --save react-transition-group
npm install --save react-popper
```

```
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { Button, ButtonGroup, NavDropdown, Collapse, Navbar, 
    NavbarToggler, NavbarBrand, Nav, NavItem, NavLink,
    Dropdown, DropdownMenu, DropdownToggle, DropdownItem, UncontrolledDropdown } from 'reactstrap';

class MyComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggleNavbar = this.toggleNavbar.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };
    }

    toggleNavbar() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        });
    }
    render(){
    return (
      <div>            
        <Navbar color="faded" light expand="md">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">
                <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank"><img src={logo} alt="Logo" /></a>
                <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank"><h2 className="header-title">My Site</h2></a>
            </NavbarBrand>                
            <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNavbar} />
            <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar className="collapse">
              <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar pullRight>
                <NavItem><LinkContainer to="/admin"><NavLink>Home</NavLink></LinkContainer></NavItem>
                <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                  <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                    Link 1
                  </DropdownToggle>
                  <DropdownMenu >
                    <LinkContainer to="/sub-link1">
                        <DropdownItem>Sub Link 1</DropdownItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                  </DropdownMenu>
                </UncontrolledDropdown>                    
                <LinkContainer to="/logout">
                    <NavItem><NavLink>Logout</NavLink></NavItem>                                        
                </LinkContainer>
              </Nav>
            </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    )
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 2):

One more option if you ise react router:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

  <DropdownMenu className="dropdown__menu">
     <Link to={`somewhere`}><DropdownItem>Edit</DropdownItem></Link>
  </DropdownMenu>
```

Comment: This option worked better for me, The button option style didnt match what I wanted. Thank you for this comment

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue. Tried originally using withRouter and adding an onClick property which called history.push(newRoute), but just learned of a simpler way:

```
const DropdownItemLink = props => {
  return <DropdownItem tag={Link} {...props}>{props.title}</DropdownItem>;
};

return (
  <div className="ActionsDropdown">
    <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
      <DropdownToggle>Actions</DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        {[
          DropdownItemLink({ 
            title: 'title1', 
            to: 'path1',
          }), 
          DropdownItemLink({ 
            title: 'title2', 
            to: 'path2',
          }), 
          ...
        ]}
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
  </div>
);
```

Need to import Link from 'react-router-dom' library and obviously all the dropdown components from 'reactstrap' library. And also need to properly manage this.state.dropdownOpen and this.toggle according to reactstrap documentation.

Comment: Seems like there is some discussion on what component to use, but 'Tag' should be the accepted answer https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/83

Answer (score 0):

Can you add anchor tag to DropdownItem like this?

```
  <DropdownItem  classname='dropdown-item' > <a href="http://localhost:3000/vitae" target="_blank"> LINKS</DropdownItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using react-router Link for few months inside DropdownItem until i realized it didnt worked in firefox !.. It worked fine in chrome.. looks like the right way is to use the onClick prop ...

```
<DropdownItem id={e.id} key={e.id} onClick={this.changeValue}>{e.name}</DropdownItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reactstrap documentation is poor.

Examine the src for supported props and render logic

This will render as <a>

You use that syntax in your example so not sure why it doesn't work as DropdownItem hasn't been changed since before you posted.

```
<DropdownItem href="/link">A link</DropdownItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a nested `DropDownMenu` inside another `DropDownMenu`.

Add `toggle={false}` to `DropDownMenuItem` and override CSS events solved my problem

**JSX:**

```
<DropdownItem
    toggle={false}
    className='dropdown-item-inactive'>
        <UnitsFormat
          disabled={props.isLoading}
          unitsFormat={props.unitsFormat}
          onChange={props.onUnitFormatChanged} />
</DropdownItem>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-item-inactive:active {
    color: inherit!important;
    background-color: #ffffff!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using reactstrap. so this is the best option. in this option, you can set react-router link tag.

```js
<Button tag={Link} color="primary" to="{{url}}">know more</Button>
```